# How to Send email with line breaks in php

Tags: php, email

Please help me to make code message in line break. i didn't know how to do this please check my code. hope you help  me out. thanks alot in advance:-

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "mymail@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['name']; // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['name'];
$mail=$_POST['email'];
$msg=$_POST['message'];

$phone= $_POST['mob'];


$subject = "contact";
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
$message =  "Name:-". $first_name . "Email:-". $mail . "Phone Number:- 
   ".$phone. " Message:-".$msg." " ;

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

 ?>
```

I want to recieve message like this:-

```
   Name:-loreal
   email:- Mymail
   phone Number:- 987654321
   Message:- Hi
```

Comment: In plain text linebreak is `"\n"`, in html - `<br />`.

Comment: Hi thanks @u_mulder will you please make this in answer over my code thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Try using `\n` in your message as:

```
$message =  " Name:-". $first_name . "\n Email:-". $mail . "\n Phone Number:- 
   ".$phone. "\n Message:-".$msg." " ;
```

They're escape sequences. `\n` is a newline and `\r` is a carriage return. `\r` is a Carriage Return `\n` is a Line Feed (or new line)

- Mac: `\r`
- Linux/Unix: `\n`
- Windows: `\r\n`

Comment: no in this it's show br in message which is tottaly wrong and also it's show in one line :( 

this is i get message right now 

 Name:-loreal <br> email:- Mymail <br> phone Number:- 987654321 <br> Message:- Hi

Comment: Try using `\n` instead of `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

When you are using html tags in email template then you have to mention content type in headers and you have to include that headers in mail function like this

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Answer (score 0):

For HTML mail use proper headers:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $to = "mymail@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
        $from = $_POST['name']; // this is the sender's Email address
        $first_name = $_POST['name'];
        $mail=$_POST['email'];
        $msg=$_POST['message'];
        $phone= $_POST['mob'];
        $subject = "contact";
        $message = "Name:-". $first_name . "<br/>Email:-". $mail . "<br/>Phone Number:-".$phone. "<br/>Message:-".$msg." " ;
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "mymail@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['name']; // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];

$phone= $_POST['mob'];

$subject = "contact";
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
$message =  "Name:-" . $first_name . "\n\n" . "Email:-" . $mail . "\n\n" . "Phone Number:- " .$phone . "\n\n" . " Message:- " . $msg;

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers .= " MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; #Define MIME Version
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; #Set content type

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

header('Location: thank-you.php');
    }
    else{
echo 'Your message cannot be sent.';
}

?>
```